# How to find lines in a file matching lines in another file?

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a large file with 11 columns of either text or numbers:

```
ETNOFIKK 03001 E0146 a1 1001 0146 10303001 10 500 EKO24 2001_200

ETNOFIKK 03002 E0147 a1 1001 0147 10303002 10 500 EKO24 2001_200

ETNOFIKK 03003 E0148 a1 1001 0148 10303003 10 500 EKO24 2001_200
```

...

and another file of only one column of numbers:

```
0146

0148
```

...

I need to extract lines from the first file when the 6th column matches the entries of the second file. So, in the above example, if the second file contains only the two entries, then the first and the third lines are printed from the first file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} $6 in a' file2 file1
ETNOFIKK 03001 E0146 a1 1001 0146 10303001 10 500 EKO24 2001_200
ETNOFIKK 03003 E0148 a1 1001 0148 10303003 10 500 EKO24 2001_200
```

This store the `file2` (index) in an array 
Then look if `$6` is equal in the array, yes, print line.

Comment: Thanks indeed, fast in answer and operation.

Comment: use a[$1] may be better, who knows the original file2 has white space or not. Second, the orginal files have empty lines in both file1 and file2, if the empty line existed, your command's output will be wrong with several empty line as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/^/^\\([^[:blank:]]\\{1,\\}[[:blank:]]\\{1,\\}\\)\\{5\\}/' Other.file > /tmp/pregrep.txt
egrep -f /tmp/pregrep.txt Source.File
```

Use of sed only is possible (after a cat of both file and a pipe) but lot more instruction. So awk of Jotne seems to be the champ

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR &&NF{a[$1];next} $6 in a' file2 file1
```